Manipulating a sum
I have the following sum:
$$ S = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(n\pi)}{(n+1)^2}$$
I'm asked to solve it using the following result:
Let $f(z)$ be a complex function with it's poles $z_{k} \not\in \mathbb{Z}$ and such that
$|z\cdot f(z)| \to 0$ for $|z|\to \infty$, then we can prove that:
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} f(n) = -\pi\sum_{k}Res\left(f(z)\cdot \cot(\pi z);\:z_{k}\right)$$
But I have a problem in turning the initial sum into the form
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} $$
Because $f(n)$ is not even so I can't just add the sum for $ n \to -n $ and take half of it. I know that at $n=-1$ I just need to add a term $i\epsilon$ in the denominator and subtract the new term at $n=-1$ which will be in the form of something like $ -\frac{1}{i\epsilon}$ and then at the end take the limit for $\epsilon \to 0$.
Any help is appreciated.

Observe that $;\cos n\pi=(-1)^n;$ ....can't you use complex power series?

Using the Basel Problem
Using the answer to the Basel Problem: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$; we get
$$
\begin{align}
S
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{(n+1)^2}\tag{1a}\\
S+1
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{(n+1)^2}\tag{1b}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}\tag{1c}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n)^2}\tag{1d}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\tag{1e}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{12}\tag{1f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ original formula
$\text{(1b):}$ add $1$ to both sides
$\text{(1c):}$ $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$ then substitute $n\mapsto n-1$
$\text{(1d):}$ alternating sum is the whole sum minus twice the sum of the even terms
$\text{(1e):}$ simplify
$\text{(1f):}$ apply the answer to the Basel problem
This says that
$$
S=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-1\tag2
$$

Using the Suggested Formula
$$
\begin{align}
S
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{(n+1)^2}\tag{3a}\\
S+1
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{(n+1)^2}\tag{3b}\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{n^2}\tag{3c}\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sec(n\pi)}{n^2}\tag{3d}\\
&=-\frac12\sum_{|n|\ge1}\frac{\sec(n\pi)}{n^2}\tag{3e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a):}$ original formula
$\text{(3b):}$ add $1$ to both sides
$\text{(3c):}$ substitute $n\mapsto n-1$
$\text{(3d):}$ $\cos(n\pi)=\sec(n\pi)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$
$\text{(3e):}$ the summand is even
$$
\begin{align}
S+1-\frac12\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{\pi\csc(\pi z)}{z^2}\right)
&=-\frac12\int_\gamma\frac{\sec(\pi z)}{z^2}\pi\cot(\pi z)\,\mathrm{d}z\tag{4a}\\
&=-\frac12\int_\gamma\frac{\pi\csc(\pi z)}{z^2}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag{4b}\\[3pt]
&=0\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a):}$ $\pi\cot(\pi z)$ has residue $1$ at each $z\in\mathbb{Z}$, multiplying by $-\frac12\frac{\sec(\pi z)}{z^2}$ and
$\phantom{\text{(4a):}}$ integrating picks up the terms in $\text{(3e)}$ minus $\frac12\operatorname*{Res}\limits_{z=0}\left(\frac{\sec(\pi z)}{z^2}\pi\cot(\pi z)\right)$,
$\phantom{\text{(4a):}}$ which is $S+1-\frac12\operatorname*{Res}\limits_{z=0}\left(\pi\frac{\csc(\pi z)}{z^2}\right)$
$\phantom{\text{(4a):}}$ the singularities in $-\frac12\frac{\sec(\pi z)}{z^2}$ where $z-\frac12\in\mathbb{Z}$ are cancelled by $\pi\cot(\pi z)$
$\text{(4b):}$ simplify
$\text{(4c):}$ $|\csc(x+iy)|\le|\operatorname{csch}(y)|$ and
$\phantom{\text{(4c):}}$ $|\csc(x+iy)|=\operatorname{sech}(y)$ when $x\equiv\frac\pi2\pmod\pi$
Since $\operatorname*{Res}\limits_{z=0}\left(\frac{\pi\csc(\pi z)}{z^2}\right)=\frac\pi6$, this says that
$$
S=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-1\tag5
$$

Another Idea is to separation and use $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{n^2}=\frac {\pi^2}{6}$ like below
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos(n\pi)}{(n+1)^2}
=-\frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{9}-\frac{1}{16}+\frac {1}{25}-\cdots\\-(\frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{16}+\frac{1}{36}+\frac {1}{64}+\cdots)+(\frac {1}{9}+\frac{1}{25}+\frac {1}{49}+\cdots)$$ now use this hint $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\=(\frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{16}+\frac{1}{36}+\frac {1}{64}+\cdots)+(\frac 11+\frac {1}{9}+\frac{1}{25}+\frac {1}{49}+\cdots)\\
\frac 14 (\frac 11+\frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac {1}{25}+\cdots)+(\frac 11+\frac {1}{9}+\frac{1}{25}+\frac {1}{49}+\cdots)$$ so $(\frac 11+\frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac {1}{25}+\cdots)=???
\\\frac 14 A +A=\frac {\pi^2}{6}$
